# Json Path To extract array element with child Filter

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

Hi I am looking to construct a jsonpath expression to find the array element that matches the filter on a child.

Please find details below

Json

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "children": [
        {"id": 101, "name": "Child1"},
        {"id": 102, "name": "Child2"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "children": [
        {"id": 201, "name": "Child3"},
        {"id": 202, "name": "Child4"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "children": [
      {"id": 201, "name": "Child3"},
      {"id": 202, "name": "Child4"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find the parent element which has the children with id=201

Please find the expression I have tried with respective results.

**Expression 1:
**

```
$.items[?(@.children[?(@.id == 201)])]
```

Result:

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":101,"name":"Child1"},{"id":102,"name":"Child2"}]},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":201,"name":"Child3"},{"id":202,"name":"Child4"}]}]
```

```
$.items[?(@.children[*].id == 201)]
```

Result: []

Note: I am using Jayway Library and have tried the solutions by chatgpt

Any Help would be appreciated .

Thanks in Advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGSnl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVdB9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Jayway supports nested queries like your first attempt.

Note that it does work on my playground, https://json-everything.net/json-path.  Mine implements the upcoming IETF specification in .Net.

You might be able to find another library that will work for youon the [comparison site](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/).

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response.
It worked on json objects but the same fails for json arraya

Answer (score 0):

Using JsonPath-Plus
This query on the origninal dataset:

```
items[*].children[?(@.id==201)]^^
```

will produce

```
[
  { "id": 2, "children": 
    [ 
      { "id": 201, "name": "Child3" },
      { "id": 202, "name": "Child4" } 
    ]
  }
]
```

$.items[*].children[?(@.id==201)]^^ produces the same result.

The [JSONPath Demo](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/demo/?) site allows you to put in a dataset, a filter/query and see the results.
Above, the query is:

1. Getting all the items
2. filtering the children by the ID==201
3. Getting the parent with the '^' operator. This goes up two generations in order to get the shape of the data that you wanted.